# On the existence of a finitely indexed subgroup of unit circle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Have a look at this question:

Which of the following groups has a proper subgroup of finite index

a. $(\mathbb{Q},+)$.

b. $(\mathbb{R},+)$.

c. $S^1=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ associated with complex multiplication.

d. $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z},(+,+))$

Clearly, $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$ cannot tolerate a proper subgroup having finite index, as $nx \in N \leq \Bbb R ~(\Bbb Q)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R~(\Bbb Q)$ implies $N=\Bbb R~(\Bbb Q)$. Also, $2\Bbb Z \times 2 \Bbb Z$ can form such a subgroup for $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Further, I feel that $S^1$ also cannot have a finitely indexed subgroup, but how to justify?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Hint**: there is a surjective homomorphism $(\mathbb{R}, +) \to S^{1}$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Ya...I got the inverse image $\varphi^{-1}(N)$ is a subgroup in $\Bbb R$, where $N$ is a subgroup of $S^1$ of finite index and $\varphi(t)=e^{i t},~t \in \Bbb R$. How can I reach at a contradiction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Hint 2** Use the third isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I couldn't connect the normal subgroups $\varphi^{-1}(N)$ and $H=\{2k\pi~:~k \in \Bbb Z\}$ of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The third isomorphism theorem tells you among others that $\mathbb{R}/\varphi^{-1}(N) \cong S^{1}/N$.